# error in starting service from broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I'm very new in services so please bear with me. I'm trying to start a service class from my broadcastreceiver but the app crashes. In my broadcastreceiver I'm checking for incoming sms and insert into database and then start service.

### Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.anew"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.example.anew.MyBroadcast">
            <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
               <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>  
       <service android:name=".LocalService" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

### Service

```
public class LocalService extends Service {

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    String resource, Time, Mesg, webResponse;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    } 

    @Override  
    public void onCreate() {  
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    }  

    @Override  
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {  
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student WHERE id=(SELECT MIN(id) FROM student)", null);
        if(c.getCount()==0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No SMS found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }
        else if(c.moveToNext()) {
            Sender = c.getString(1);
            TimeStamp = c.getString(2);
            Mesg = c.getString(3); 
        }
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/createsms.asmx/broadcast?"); 

        //Post Data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("a", "AB1"));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("b", "IN"));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("c", resource));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("d", Time));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("e", Mesg));

        //Encoding POST data
        try{
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        //making POST request.
        try{
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            String XmlString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            XmlString=XmlString.replaceAll("\\<\\?xml(.+?)\\?\\>", "").trim();
            XmlString = XmlString.substring(XmlString.indexOf("[") + 1, XmlString.lastIndexOf("]"));
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(XmlString);
            webResponse = jObj.getString("status");
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // Log exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Log exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } // onStart ends 

    @Override  
    public void onDestroy() {  
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    } 
}
```

### Broadcastreceiver

```java
public class MyBroadcast  extends BroadcastReceiver {

    Context mContext;   

    String msg_body;    
    String mob_no, name;
    String dttm, key;
    SQLiteDatabase db;


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db=context.openOrCreateDatabase("StudentDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
            final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
            }
            StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
            if (messages.length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                    content.append(messages[i].getMessageBody());
                    mob_no = messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    Date finaldate = calendar.getTime();
                    dttm = finaldate.toString();    
                }
            }
            msg_body = content.toString();

            Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(mob_no));
            Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME},null,null,null);
            try {
                if(c.moveToFirst()) {
                   name = c.getString(0);
                   db.execSQL("INSERT INTO student (sender, timestamp, mesg) VALUES('"+name+"','"+dttm+"','"+msg_body+"');");
                   context.startService(new Intent(context,LocalService.class));
                } else {
                   db.execSQL("INSERT INTO student (sender,timestamp,mesg) VALUES('"+mob_no+"','"+dttm+"','"+msg_body+"');");
                   context.startService(new Intent(context,LocalService.class));
                }   
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            } finally {
                c.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### LogCat

```html
10-08 11:45:44.776: E/AndroidRuntime(15029): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-08 11:45:44.776: E/AndroidRuntime(15029): Process: com.example.anew, PID: 15029
10-08 11:45:44.776: E/AndroidRuntime(15029): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.anew.LocalService@41e40438 with Intent { cmp=com.example.anew/.LocalService }: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-08 11:45:44.776: E/AndroidRuntime(15029):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2923)
10-08 11:45:44.776: E/AndroidRuntime(15029):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:155)
10-08 11:45:44.776: E/AndroidRuntime(15029):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1428)
10-08 11:45:44.776: E/AndroidRuntime(15029):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
10-08 11:45:44.776: E/AndroidRuntime(15029):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
10-08 11:45:44.776: E/AndroidRuntime(15029):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5388)
10-08 11:45:44.776: E/AndroidRuntime(15029):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-08 11:45:44.776: E/AndroidRuntime(15029):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-08 11:45:44.776: E/AndroidRuntime(15029):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-08 11:45:44.776: E/AndroidRuntime(15029):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:655)
10-08 11:45:44.776: E/AndroidRuntime(15029):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-08 11:45:44.776: E/AndroidRuntime(15029): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-08 11:45:44.776: E/AndroidRuntime(15029):  at com.example.anew.LocalService.onStart(LocalService.java:51)
10-08 11:45:44.776: E/AndroidRuntime(15029):  at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:450)
10-08 11:45:44.776: E/AndroidRuntime(15029):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2906)
10-08 11:45:44.776: E/AndroidRuntime(15029):  ... 10 more
```

Comment: database is working fine as i'm checking in MainActivity layout. Its the service which is not starting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student 
                  WHERE id=(SELECT MIN(id) FROM student)", null);
```

`db` object is `null` becuase not initilized anywhere in service.do it as:

```
db=LocalService.this.openOrCreateDatabase("StudentDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student 
                  WHERE id=(SELECT MIN(id) FROM student)", null);
```

Comment: Thanks so much man. The app is not crashing due to the service not starting error.